# Akka: What is the equivalent of Flow in Java

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-stream

Akka streams in scala provides a Flow concept. What is the equivalent in Java?

For example, in Scala, there is Flow.take(n)

but in Java, there is Source.take(n) which returns a source not a flow

Comment: It's recommended to first read the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Flow.html#take(long)). The Java and Scala Flow` APIs are indeed similar.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://akka.io/docs/) clearly indicates, the Akka libraries--including Akka Streams--all have a Java API as well as a Scala API, so the Java equivalent of [`Flow # take`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html#take(n:Long):FlowOps.this.Repr[Out]) is...[`Flow # take`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.6/akka/stream/javadsl/Flow.html#take(long)).